# Nestjs app triggering CORS error despite CORS being enabled

Tags: nestjs

I'm building a relatively simple React Native app with a nestjs backend.

My React Native app is making a POST request to `localhost:3000/blah`. This results in this error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/blah' from origin 'http://localhost:19006' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

On the nestjs backend side, in main.ts before `await app.listen(3000);`, I have tried the following:

```
  app.enableCors();
```

as well as

```
  app.enableCors({
    allowedHeaders: ['content-type', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'],
    origin: "http://localhost:19006",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS",
    preflightContinue: true,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
  });
```

But both still result in the same error on the client.

The only thing that seems to fix it is if the app makes the request with

```
...fetch(URL, {mode: 'no-cors', ...})
```

but that isn't the most secure, from my understanding.

Am I missing something about how CORS works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question: I was doing something silly elsewhere and the problem had little to do with CORS. In the end, modifying my `main.ts` file in the nestjs backend in this simple way did work, as suggested by the internet:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.enableCors();

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

The reason it *didn't* seem like it was working at first was because I don't think nestjs was automatically rebuilding all the backend files correctly upon any edit as it should. This is because, in the process of trying to fix something else, I modified my `tsconfig.json` file in the backend to include this:

```
include: []
```

In retrospect this was a bit silly - this means that none of my typescript files were being compiled! The symptom of this was that my `backend/dist/` directory was empty, and when I tried to run `npm build`, the backend complained that nothing was in `backend/dist/`.

Weirdly enough, under the wrong configuration, I ended up in a state where the frontend would complain of a CORS problem, but the backend would continue to get the right API call (as evidenced by tripping a debugger), but the POST requests's body wasn't coming through.

Hope this helps somebody in the future work through their problem! `app.enableCors()` did do the trick for me here.

Answer (score 0):

Better approach while development process is proxy. you can configure it in your **vite.config.ts** file. [please read this link](https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy), and prevent cors error. Also you can try this option instead of `app.enableCors();`

```
const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, { cors: true });
```

Comment: Unfortunately putting the cors setting into NestFactory.create didn't help. Will look into the idea of a proxy, though I'm surprised it's this much trouble to get a local React Native frontend to speak to my local backend!